# Why are hashing algorithms safe to use?

Tags: algorithm, security, hash

Hashing algorithms today are widely used to check for integrity of data, but why are they safe to use? A 256-bit hashing algorithm generates 256 bits representation of given data. However, a 256-bit hash only has 2<sup>512</sup> variations. But 1 KB of data has 2<sup>8192</sup> different variations. It's mathematically impossible for every piece of data in the world to have different hash values. So why are hashing algorithms safe?

Comment: This should probably be migrated to Computer Scientists or Security

Comment: @KelvinZhang Click the StackExchange menu at the top of this page. Close to the bottom there is a search bar where you can find other communities. Type in "security" for example to bring up the correct community.

Comment: what you are looking for is called "hash collision". It is when 2 contents have the same hash. They are very rare due to a/ the construct of the hash algorithms and b/ the entropy of the content itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It could on-topic in http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: There are two main types of hash functions. 1. Those where collisions are allowable such as those used in dictionary lookup functions that use a secondary method such as re-hashing or full comparison to eliminate ambiguity. 2. Those that are collision resistant such as cryptographic hash functions where a single bit difference in the input will cause approximately 50% of the output bits to change. SHA-256 is of the second type and safe to use to determine if two files are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reasons why hashing algorithms are considered safe are due to the following:

1. They are irreversible. You can't get to the input data by reverse-engineering the output hash value.
2. A small change in the input will produce a vastly different hash value. i.e. "hello" vs "hellp" will generate completely different values.

The assumption being made with data integrity is that a majority of your input is going to be the same between a good copy of input data and a bad (malicious) copy of input data. The small change in data will make the hash value completely different. Therefore, if I try to inject any malicious code or data, that small change will completely throw-off the value of the hash. When comparison is done with a known hash value, it'll be easily determinable if data has been modified or corrupted.

You are correct in that there is risk of collisions between an infinite number of datasets, but when you compare two datasets that are very similar, it is reasonable to assume that the hash values of those two almost-equivalent datasets with be completely different.

Comment: Do their irreversibilities rely on the fact that data is longer than the hash?

Comment: In a way yes. Since you're reducing an infinite number of possibilities of input values into a discrete number of output hash values, you have an infinite number of values that the input could have been, making the true input indeterminable.

Comment: I'm not too happy with this answer, as it misses the question in my opinion. The answer to his question is mostly pure statistics: *what is the probability of collisions*. Depending of the nature of the environment, remark 2 of this answer could be important (collision-distribution). I don't think remark 1 adds something to this (as i understood the question; it's important in crypto). Also remark 1 is not always valid, as non-cryptographic hash-functions usually have no reason to counter the inversion, so it might be possible to generate x, so that f(x)=y (not a reconstruction; but relevant).

Comment: It's also a special constraint to make a cryprographic hash-function hard to invert. While the different bit-lenghts have some effect, this characteristic is implemented with extra-care designing the algorithm (compare with block-ciphers, where the length doesn't change, but in inversion is nearly impossible).

Comment: @Mackers That's only part of the story. Compression algorithms compact the data yet the result is reversible

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername The analysis of this remark can get very complex if one argues with the pigeonhole-principle to reason, that on average (on every possible input) no input get's compressed (input-size = output-size). But it's also a good example which provokes some thoughts about this answer.

Comment: @sascha The probability of collision is 100% given a data longer than the hash.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Not all files can be compressed into smaller sizes.

Comment: @Kelvin Zhang That's not a meaningful model of looking at it. Or do you think that a hash-function which maps to 4 bits (instead of something like 256) would gain widespread use? They both suffer equally with this kind of analysis.

Comment: Another important aspect not in the answer's list is that it's very hard to calculate or stumble upon some further change (e.g. fiddle a few characters in an unimportant comment or message) which would restore the hash value to that of the original unaltered data, to hide that the content's been modified.

Comment: @KelvinZhang That's irrelevant. Hash function should be equally suitable for all kinds of data.

Comment: @KelvinZhang Collisions are inevitable, true. However, if they can be found easily (i.e., significantly easier than brute-force), the function is considered insecure. Otherwise, the length of the hash provides enough security to withstand brute-force attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Not all hashes are safe. There are good hashes (for some value of "good") where it's sufficiently non-trivial to intentionally create collisions (I think FNV-1a may fall in this category). However, a cryptographic hash, used correctly, would be computationally expensive to generate a collision for.

"Good" hashes generally have the property that small changes in the input cause large changes in the output (rule of thumb is that a single-bit flip in the input cause roughly b bit flips in the output, for a 2b hash). There are some special-purpose hashes where "close inputs generate close hashes" is actually a feature, but you probably would not use those for error detecting, but they may be useful for other applications.

A specific use for FNV-1a is to hash large blocks of data, then compare the computed hash to that of other blocks. Only blocks that have a matching hash need to be fully compared to see if they're identical, meaning that a large number of blocks can simply be ignored, speeding up the comparison by orders of magnitude (you can compare one 2 MB to another in approximately the same time as you can compare its 64-bit hash to that of the hash of 256Ki blocks; although you will probbaly have a few blocks that have colliding hashes).

Note that "just a hash" may not be enough to provide security, you may also need to apply some sort of signing mechanism to ensure that you don't have the problem of someone modifying the hashed-over text as well as the hash.

Simply for ensuring storage integrity (basically "protect against accidental modification" as a threat model), a cryptographic hash without signature, plus the original size, should be good enough. You would need a really really unlikely sequence of random events mutating a fixed-length bit string to another fixed-length bit string of the same length, giving the same hash. Of course, this does not give you any sort of error correction ability, just error detection.